# Java sum nested property of partial list using IntStream.range

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, sum, java-stream

I have this basic code (the list have size greater than 2).

```
int delayedSamples = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 2; i++) {
  delayedSamples += list.get(i).getChunk().length / size;
}
```

Is it possible to replace the before code with `IntStream.range`? like:

```
int delayedSamples = IntStream
    .range(0, list.size() - 1)
    .mapToObj(i -> list.get(i).getChunk().length / size).... ??
```

Is there lambda alternative?

Comment: You almost had it. But why are you suddenly using `list.size() - 1` instead of `list.size() - 2` when turning to a Stream? And why `mapToObj` when you want to sum `int` values? Just use `map` and append `sum()` and you’re done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
int delayedSamples = list.stream()
                         .map(item -> item.getChunk())
                         .limit(list.size() - 2)
                         .collect(Collectors.summingInt(chunk -> chunk.length / size));
```

Comment: I think moving `/ size` to the end is not equivalent, because it looks like the numbers involved may all be integers. In general, `a/size + b/size` won't equal `(a + b) / size` for ints.

Comment: What about `list.stream().limit(list.size() - 2).collect(Collectors.summingInt(item -> item.getChunk().length)) / size;` I'm not using `map(...)`

Comment: @QA_Col it’s smarter to use the other way round: `list.stream().limit(list.size() - 2) .mapToInt(item -> item.getChunk().length).sum() / size;` with a mapping step, but without a generic `collect`. Mind that while apply `/size` to the end result is more efficient, the result may differ as your original code accumulated rounding errors.